# Running Migrations Automatically pre_start in Elixir-Distillery-Release on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, elixir, database-migration, distillery

i need your help!
im trying to run migrations in a distillery release (Elixir-Application) before the application starts automatically (via Boot Hooks -https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/boot-hooks.html#content).
Development and Production platform must be Windows.

The Problem: I cant find any infos about Windows (.bat)-Scripts referencing the problem - I search for a script for the "pre_start.bat"-File - for calling the ERTS Node and finally my Elixir-Code in it.

my distillery-config : rel\config.exs

```
environment :prod do
  ...
  set pre_start_hook: "rel/hooks/pre_start"
  ...
end
```

The required script should call my code of the "Elixir.MyApp.ReleaseTask.migrate"-Function
How can i achieve this??

The following Code is what ive got so far.. but it doesnt work ..

```
@echo off
echo Running migrations
echo.
echo.
echo.
cd %RELEASE_ROOT_DIR%

@set system_erl="<erl_directory>\erts-9.1\bin\erl.exe"
@set erl=%system_erl%
@set system_root_dir_cmd=%system_erl% -noshell -eval "io:format(\"~s\", [filename:nativename(code:root_dir())])." -s init stop
@set rootdir=%system_root%
@set system_erts_vsn_cmd=%system_erl% -noshell -eval "Ver=erlang:system_info(version),io:format(\"~s\", [Ver])" -s init stop
@set erts_vsn=%system_erts_vsn%
@set erts_dir=%rootdir%\erts-%erts_vsn%

@set rel_name="my_api"
@set rel_vsn="1.0"
@set consolidated_dir=%rootdir%\lib\%rel_name%-%rel_vsn%\consolidated

@%erl% -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR "%erts_dir%\..\lib" ^
       -hidden -noshell -boot start_clean ^
       -pa "%consolidated_dir%" ^
       -s "Elixir.MyApp.ReleaseTasks" "seed" -s init stop

echo Migrations run successfully
```

Please correct me when im totally wrong with this.
Any help appreciated! BTW its a phoenix-Application.

Comment: Is there any reason you use `.bat` file for this? I would produce an erlang’s native `escript` running this particular function and use it as `pre_start`.

Comment: You do not need `@` symbols in front of all your lines of code.   Once you have declared `@echo off`, they are no longer needed to suppress verbose output.

Comment: @mudasobwa can u roughly explain how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @Squashman thanks for Info

Comment: In your code you have the following variables which appear to have no known value, `%RELEASE_ROOT_DIR%`, `%system_root%` and `%system_erts_vsn%`. This will mean that your variables, `%rootdir%` and `%erts_vsn%` will also have no value and that the following variables will not have the expected content `%erts_dir%` and `%consolidated_dir%`. Also you have set `%erl%` needlessly because it's content matches `%system_erl%`, which never changes and both `%system_root_dir_cmd%` and `%system_erts_vsn_cmd%` seem to be unused. Additionally when you use `set`, the correct syntax is `Set "Var=Value"`.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with erlang’s native `escript` instead. To build it:

**1. update `mix.exs`**, e.g. add:

```
escript: [main_module: MyApp, path: "bin/migrator"]
```

to the array returned by `MyApp.Mixfile.project/0` function and add `bin` directory to the release:

```
#         ⇓⇓⇓
files: ~w|bin lib mix.exs README.md|,
```

to the array returned by `MyApp.Mixfile.package/0`

**2. create `MyApp.main/1`** function:

```
def main(_args) do
  MyApp.ReleaseTasks.migrate
end
```

You are all set. There in release will be `escript` in `bin/migrator` (the name you used in step 1.)

Now you should be able to run `bin/migrator`, since it’s a plain old good executable.

*Sidenote:* `mix compile` would build this executable as well, so you might play with it and test it before running with `distillery`.

Comment: what do mean with and add bin directory to the release:

#         ⇓⇓⇓
files: ~w|bin lib mix.exs README.md|,
to the array returned by MyApp.Mixfile.package/0

Comment: I am unsure how can I express myself better. Add `bin` directory to the list of `files` inside `project` function of your `mix.exs` file.

Comment: ok i figured out what you mean.. i did everything like you said. Moreover i generated the escript with "mix escript.build". (bin/migrator) is now in my project-structure. When i build via Distillery (mix release --env=prod), i cannot find the migrator-executable in my release folder. Do i miss something? Thanks for your fast answers!